# Misbehavior of elements in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, frontend

I am debugging our current site for IE7 and there is one bug I just can't figure out.

If you go to page: http://zanadu.cn/package/137 (using IE7) and scroll up and down you can see the bug.

Basically, there is a panel with calendars that stays on the top after scrolling past it. But then there are 2 issues:

1. The Text under the sticky panel gets pushed down. Every time you re-attach the sticky panel (scroll all the way up and down again) it moves a little bit more down. I have completely no idea why. Nothing is pushing it from the top.
2. When you scroll all the way up and the panel is re-attached, the content of the panel (calendars and button) is not visible.

Now I have tried all possible and still cannot figure out what's wrong. If you go to developer tools in IE, refresh the markup after scrolling, select the sticky panel element, open up computed styles and untick the `position:relative`, suddenly everything goes back to normal. There is no way to reproduce this programmatically (at least I didn't find any way).

I am pretty sure that the best and simplest answer is: This is just buggy behavior of old IE. The problem is that company is pushing me to fix it, so what should I do... If I cannot find solution, I'm just going to prevent on old IE for the top panel to stick...

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion? Force the latest IE rendering engine using this

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

A lot of people and companies are moving away from supporting IE7, it has a lot of issues and frankly users need to stick with the times. Just my opinion.

Comment: Trust me, same opinion here, the problem is that this is website for china, and the browser situation there.. well it completely blows... They are actually using a chinese browser mutant, that is based on IE core, its called 360 browser. That piece of software is abomination to any development ever done.. anyway it was based on IE6 until this summer, now they "finally" moved to IE7 core, so about 80% of china got updated to IE7 (as 360 comes with PC when you buy it and uninstall it is practically impossible.), so I still need to optimize for IE7..